# Go Converting an integer from a string

Tags: string, go

Recently while taking some algorithm practise at leetcode i came across a solution, i understood everything except the part where the user converts an element in a string to an integer, look at the code below. Hopefully someone can explain this to me. Thanks for replies in advnace.

```
a := 234
b := strconv.Itoa(a)
c := int(b[0]-48) // why do we subtract 48?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`48` is the code of the `'0'` character in the ASCII table.

Go stores strings as their UTF-8 byte sequences in memory, which maps characters of the ASCII table one-to-one to their code.

The digits in the ASCII table are listed contiguously, `'0'` being `48`. So if you have a digit in a string, and you subtract 48 from the character's code, you get the digit as a numeric value.

Indexing a `string` indexes its bytes, and in your case `b[0]` is the first byte of the `b` string, which is `2`. And `'2' - 48` is `2`.

For example:

```
fmt.Println('0' - 48)
fmt.Println('1' - 48)
fmt.Println('2' - 48)
fmt.Println('3' - 48)
fmt.Println('4' - 48)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RoprPGORdeO)):

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

“b” is a string “234”, a string is a slice of rune therefore b[0] is a byte/rune, in this case a value of 50 which is the decimal value of a “2” in ascii. So “c” will be 50-48=2